# How do I import a CSV file into two related PostgreSQL tables?

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, import, foreign-keys

Let's say I have a two column CSV file called "**objects.csv**" (*first line = headers*) with the following lines:

```
colour,object
red,apple
blue,sky
blue,sea
red,plane
green,grass
red,car
red,ship
blue,pool
blue,towel
red,raincoat
green,hat
green,jumper
green,lawnmower
red,strawberry
red,cherry
blue,icicle
```

I have a database with two related tables created using the following SQL script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.colours (
    colour_id serial NOT NULL,
    colour text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT colours_pkey PRIMARY KEY (colour_id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.objects (
    object_id serial NOT NULL,
    object text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT objects_pkey PRIMARY KEY (object_id),
    objects_colour_id_fkey integer REFERENCES colours(colour_id)
);
```

The `colours` table contains the following values:

```
colour_id,colour
1,red
2,green
3,blue
```

I need to import the CSV file into the database such that the colour values in the first CSV column are 'replaced' with the associated foreign keys from the colours table, so the objects table will contain:

```
1,apple
3,sky
3,sea
1,plane
2,grass
1,car
1,ship
3,pool
3,towel
1,raincoat
2,hat
2,jumper
2,lawnmower
1,strawberry
1,cherry
3,icicle
```

It's importing a flat file into two normalized 'related' tables.

### **How do I achieve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a landing table and use the psql `\copy` command to land the data:

```
CREATE TABLE public.colours (
    colour_id serial NOT NULL,
    colour text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT colours_pkey PRIMARY KEY (colour_id)
);
CREATE TABLE

CREATE TABLE public.objects (
    object_id serial NOT NULL,
    object text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT objects_pkey PRIMARY KEY (object_id),
    objects_colour_id_fkey integer REFERENCES colours(colour_id)
);
CREATE TABLE

create table objects_landing (colour text, object text);
CREATE TABLE
\copy objects_landing from 'objects.csv' csv header;
COPY 16

insert into colours (colour)
select distinct colour               
  from objects_landing  
 where not exists(
         select 1 from colours
          where colour = objects_landing.colour);
INSERT 0 3

insert into objects (object, objects_colour_id_fkey)
select distinct l.object, c.colour_id
  from objects_landing l
       join colours c
         on c.colour = l.colour
 where not exists (select 1
                     from objects
                    where object = l.object
                      and objects_colour_id_fkey = c.colour_id);
INSERT 0 16
```

Results:

```
select * from objects;
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ object_id │   object   │ objects_colour_id_fkey │
├───────────┼────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│         1 │ apple      │                      3 │
│         2 │ car        │                      3 │
│         3 │ cherry     │                      3 │
│         4 │ grass      │                      1 │
│         5 │ hat        │                      1 │
│         6 │ icicle     │                      2 │
│         7 │ jumper     │                      1 │
│         8 │ lawnmower  │                      1 │
│         9 │ plane      │                      3 │
│        10 │ pool       │                      2 │
│        11 │ raincoat   │                      3 │
│        12 │ sea        │                      2 │
│        13 │ ship       │                      3 │
│        14 │ sky        │                      2 │
│        15 │ strawberry │                      3 │
│        16 │ towel      │                      2 │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────┘
(16 rows)

select * from colours;
┌───────────┬────────┐
│ colour_id │ colour │
├───────────┼────────┤
│         1 │ green  │
│         2 │ blue   │
│         3 │ red    │
└───────────┴────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Haven't heard of the 'landing table' idea. Thanks, will try it.

Comment: With such a landing table - if I have several processes that create this table and operate on it at the same time, is it safe provided that each of the process runs in a separate transaction?

Comment: @MichałKlimczak  That should work, but that is not my typical use case.  If, for instance, you are synchronizing following a period of disconnected operation, you should use a remote id or device id to keep the landed records segregated throughout the operation.  The big problem I see would be that the table would have frequent deletions that lead to bloat without aggressive vacuuming.  I normally truncate landing tables in my ETL/ELT operations.